# Why doesn't my code to find the length of an array work?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to find the length of an array but my code doesn't work because "length" is undeclared. How do I declare length? Thanks in advance.

```
int main(void) {

    int array1[10];
    int length;

    //Should print 10
    printf("%d", array_length(array1, length));

    return 0;
}

int array_length(int nums[], int length) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        nums[i]++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: `length = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]);`

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without using sizeof?

Comment: Yes: `length=10;`

Comment: Anyway, your `array_length` function doesn't return `length.` It's an infinete loop because `i` is never changed in the loop.

Comment: Isnt it undefined what happen? Since length is uninitialized and passed to the function that way and  used as to determine when the loops should stop.

Comment: I meant after passing in the right `length`.

Comment: int length = 10; But you will fall in an infinite loop, as @kaylum said.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead your code,you can't know length and determine at same time

```
int main()
{
int array1[10];
int length;

length=sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't work as you are not incrementing i variable in the while loop, hence the loop goes on infinitely.

```
int array_length(int nums[], int length) {
int i = 0;

while (i < length) {
nums[i]++;
i++;
}
return i;
}
```